# Connecting Html to IPFS and upload a file

Tags: javascript, html, ipfs-http-client

I have some problem of connecting my html to IPFS, I use `<script src="https://unpkg.com/ipfs-http-client@60.0.1/dist/index.min.js"></script>` instead of npm install(Because npm install seems can't run on chrome liveserver)
and here is my html and js below:
TEST.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>IPFS File Upload</title>   
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ipfs-http-client@60.0.1/dist/index.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="fileInput">
    <button id="uploadButton">Upload File to IPFS</button>
    <div id="result"></div>

    <script type="module" src="./js/TEST.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

TEST.js

```
import { require } from 'https://unpkg.com/ipfs-http-client@60.0.1/dist/index.min.js';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
    const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    const uploadButton = document.getElementById('uploadButton');
    const resultDiv = document.getElementById('result');

    uploadButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
        const file = fileInput.files[0];

        if (!file) {
            alert('Please select a file to upload.');
            return;
        }
        const IPFS = require('ipfs')
        const ipfs = await IPFS.create(); // Create an instance of Ipfs

        try {
            const { cid } = await ipfs.add(file);

            const ipfsUrl = `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/${cid.toString()}`;
            resultDiv.innerHTML = `<p>IPFS URL: <a href="${ipfsUrl}" target="_blank">${ipfsUrl}</a></p>`;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error uploading to IPFS:', error);
            resultDiv.innerHTML = '<p>Error uploading to IPFS. Check your IPFS node and try again.</p>';
        }
    });
});
```

It got error message: `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module does not provide an export named 'require'`

I tried to connect it to IPFS with multiple methods but all of them lead to similar errors, such as Ipfs, window.IpfsHttpClient `is not defined at HTMLButtonElement`. Are there any optimal solution to it?

Comment: It's not a good idea (in fact, it's a _terrible_ idea) to blindly load externally-hosted scripts without at least specifying an `integrity=""` attribute...

Comment: Anyway, that error is because the `/dist/index.min.js` file you're loading is not an ECMAScript module file, it's a plain ol' JS file (well, it's a UMD file) and you can't use UMD files with `import { x } from ''`.

Comment: are there any optimal fix for that issue?
why does it say `IPFS is not defined at HTMLButtonElement`

Comment: ...did you read or understand any of what I wrote?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really completely understand much about how IPFS works, can you briefly explain a bit more?